# Python multi websocket connection error with thread (modified)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, websocket, fastapi

I am implementing multiple socket connection in one python process.
To do this, I used thread module in python like this:

Websocket is listening in localhost and port 8000, below methods are socket event handler.
Receives requests and delegates to socket controller.

```
# User Connection Event
@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    with profiler_context("connect.prof"):
        session = socketController.onOpen(sid)

# User Message Event
@sio.on("message")
async def message(sid, data):
    with profiler_context("message.prof"):
        result: dict = socketController.onMessage(sid, data)

        await sio.emit('{}'.format("test"))
```

When user is connected, `onOpen` method connects to socket by delegating MySocket class. In other words, actual MySocket using occurs.

Not only client and this fastAPI app are connected to socket, but this fastAPI app and external socket API also are connected to socket too.

`onMessage` method receives data(= `wavBinary`, you can easily think just base64 encoded string.) and send to socket.
When called `SocketController.onMessage -> MySocket.sendData`, error occurs that socket is already closed.

```
@Singleton
class SocketController:

    __sessionService: SessionService = SessionService()
    __chatService: ChatService = ChatService()
    __testService: TestService = TestService()
    __mySocket: MySocket = MySocket()
    
    # when user connected
    def onOpen(self, sid: str) -> Session:
        session = self.__sessionService.addSession(sid)
        session = self.__mySocket.connect(session)
        return session
    
    # when user send message
    def onMessage(self, sid: str, wavBinary: str, sttSocket) -> dict[str: Session, str: UserChat, str: NalyChat]:
        session: Session = self.__sessionService.getSession(sid)
        session.addWavBinary(wavBinary)

        sttSocket.sendData(wavBinary)
        self.__mySocket.sendData(session.getSTT().getSession(), wavBinary)
    
    # when user disconnected
    def onClose(self, sid: str) -> Session:
        session = self.__sessionService.deleteSession(sid)
        return session
```

Below is actual socket management code which has overall responsibility between fastAPI socket external socket.

```
class MySocket:
    __socket = None
    __thread = None

    __api_token = settings.api_key
    __sample_rate = 16000
    __auth_header = {"Authorization": __api_token }
    __uri = "wss://..."

    def on_open(self, ws):
        log.info("{} - New User Connection Created".format(ws))

    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        transcript = json.loads(message)
        text = transcript['text']

        log.info(message)

    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        log.info("{} - Socket Error : {}".format(ws, error))

    def on_close(self, ws):
        log.info("{} - Socket Connection Closed".format(ws))

    def start(self, socket):
        socket.run_forever()

    def send(self, socket, data):
        json_data = json.dumps({"audio_data": str(data)})
        socket.send(json_data)
    
    # enable multiple websocket using thread
    def connect(self):
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            self.__uri,
            header=self.__auth_header,
            on_message=self.on_message,
            on_open=self.on_open,
            on_error=self.on_error,
            on_close=self.on_close
        )

        self.__socket = ws
        self.__thread = Thread(target=self.start, args=(ws, ))

        self.__thread.start()
    
    # send data using thread
    def sendData(self, data):
        Thread(target=self.send, args=(self.__socket, data, )).start()
    
    # getters

    def getSocketThread(self):
        return self.__socket

    def getThread(self):
        return self.__thread
```

But when I try to send data through socket, I received an error that socket is already closed.

```
Exception in thread Thread-2 (send):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "STT.py", line 36, in send
    socket.send(json_data)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websocket/_app.py", line 252, in send
    if not self.sock or self.sock.send(data, opcode) == 0:
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 285, in send
    return self.send_frame(frame)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 313, in send_frame
    l = self._send(data)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 527, in _send
    return send(self.sock, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 145, in send
    raise WebSocketConnectionClosedException("socket is already closed.")
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: socket is already closed.
```

I expect that because main python process is not terminated, socket thread has to alive, that results to send data successfully.

Why is socket connection closed?
How can I maintain socket connection?

Below is additional references.

[Note]

1. This socket class instances are managed by dictionary in main python file. So, It will be remain in memory until main python process is terminated.
2. I am using fastAPI framework.
3. I checked socket sessions are created successfully.

I am looking forward to hearing from you guys soon!!

[Summary]

1. I tried to implement **multi socket connection using thread**.
2. But when I **send data to socket** session, I received an error that **socket connection is closed**.
3. I expect that because main python process is not terminated, socket thread has to alive, that results to send data successfully.
4. With several tests, I checked that socket creation has no problem.

Comment: Thank you for such great helps. I have added entire flow for better understandings.